# NodeJS - how can get mysql result with executed query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am new in NodeJS with [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) (npm install mysql).

When I try to execute query like

```
connection.query("select ?? from users where id = ?",[["id","fname","lname"],req.body.userid],function (err, rows) {
     **here I want query which above executed**
});
```

I want query in callback function which executed.

How can I get it??.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var c = connection.query("select ?? from users where id = ?",[["id","fname","lname"],req.body.userid],function (err, rows) {
     console.log(c.sql)
});
```

Comment: How I will get the query if I am using promise?

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.query("select ?? from users where id = ?",[["id","fname","lname"],req.body.userid],function (err, rows) {
     res.send(rows);
});
```

also in preference swith the string query to :

```
"select id,fname,lname from users where id = '"+req.body.userid+"'"
```

Comment: actually, I want query in Call Back function. No I don't want switch param as string query.