# How to print the actual query which is being excicuted on node js on console

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi I am trying the following code

```
userwallet.post('/api/user/wallet/create',verifyToken,(req,res)=>{
   jwt.verify(req.token,'secretkey',(err,authData)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
        return res.sendStatus('403');
      }else{
        mysqlConnection.query("INSERT into user_wallets(uuid,user_uuid,balance,status,created_at,updated_at) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)",[uuid(),authData.id,0,'ACTIVE',new Date(),0],(err,rows,fields)=>{
          if(!err)
          return res.json({
            message:"Successfull",
            added:rows,
            authData
          });
          console.log('Wallet creation error:',err)
          return res.sendStatus('403');
        });
      }
   });
});
```

There is some trouble of executing this code on the remote machine It is not querying so I am trying to out put the query on console i was going through this answer that is not helpful

[NodeJS - how can get mysql result with executed query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064721/nodejs-how-can-get-mysql-result-with-executed-query)

Any suggestions? For troubleshooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign connection.query to a variable e.g. query and then can get the sql by query.sql. [For more detail](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers)

```
var post  = {id: 1, title: 'Hello WORLD'};

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO TABLENAME SET ?', post, function(err, 
  result) {
     // SOMETHING
 });
//HERE YOU CAN GET QUERY 
console.log(query.sql);
```

Comment: Oh my bad i was trying to log that inside the loop :(

Comment: @arunVM if it is helpful you can like the answer, it would be helpful.

Comment: @arunVM added more detail link, that would be useful as well.